# How can I improve the performance in this simple gridview display program?

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I am running a webpage built using ASP.NET, C# & DevExpress.

There is a Grid View  with a page size of 1 and a Data Source with a simple select statement:

> SELECT * FROM [SYS_IFCError] ORDER BY [CalledDateTime] DESC

The screen also uses header filters, column filters and added columns containing custom command buttons.

With just over 500 records to display, the screen takes approx 47 seconds to load every time.

Is it getting 500 records every load?

Is there any way to improve this performance?

Comment: Dont Use `*` , try to bring the Specific Column and also by above approch it may lead to SQL injection

Comment: When you run this query on the SQL Server, how much time its takes ? I can not believe that this take so much time, so you have some other issues on pages.... some call again and again on server on each row ? some extra huge viewstate open ?

Comment: Also, how many records do you actual have on the table ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to improve performance. Best way would be to implement paging algorithm on sql server. Basically, you would write a stored procedure that receives page size and page index and returns exactly the page you need. Keep in that in that case you would also have to do the filtering and sorting in procedure. Code snippet is fairly common, you should have problem finding it.

However, that being said, I must say 47 seconds for 500 records, even when paging is not on your database sever is way, way to long. So in my opinion, your first step would be to exactly pinpoint your bottleneck and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that (500) record is your need for page size, there are several ways to improve performance :

> 1. Avoid using `*` in select statment, replace it with specific columns names.
> 2. exclude any binary data like Images from your select statement.
> 3. Add Index to your order by column
> 4. finally use Excution plan in SSMS to view your query excution map, this will help you improve your query .